# customer account data and order data mismatched

Tags: customer, customer-account

One of my website having different issue.

If I logs in from account `A`, I can see orders ordered from account `A` and someone else's account.

This is happening for most of the customer account. Website running on 1.6

Was anyone having same issue in past?